# bxslider frame border issue

Tags: html, bxslider

This is the first time I am making a website, do pardon my simple question.I am using bxslider as my banner on my website. But as you can see there is excess border on the left side. How do I make it even out like the rest of the sides? 
[image]

The css style is as follow

```
    /**
 * BxSlider v4.1.2 - Fully loaded, responsive content slider
 * http://bxslider.com
 *
 * Written by: Steven Wanderski, 2014
 * http://stevenwanderski.com
 * (while drinking Belgian ales and listening to jazz)
 *
 * CEO and founder of bxCreative, LTD
 * http://bxcreative.com
 */


/** RESET AND LAYOUT
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 6px;
    padding: 0;
    *zoom: 1;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

/** THEME
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    border:  5px solid #fff;
    left: -5px;
    background: #fff;

    /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
    -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
        -ms-transform: translatez(0);
        -o-transform: translatez(0);
        transform: translatez(0);
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
    min-height: 50px;
    background: url(images/bx_loader.gif) center center no-repeat #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}

/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #666;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
    background: #666;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    outline: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
    background: #000;
}

/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
    left: 10px;
    background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
    right: 10px;
    background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover {
    background-position: -43px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
    outline: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
    display: none;
}

/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    text-align: center;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -11px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active {
    background-position: -86px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -44px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active {
    background-position: -86px -33px;
}

/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
    text-align: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
    right: 0;
    width: 35px;
}

/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #666\9;
    background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
    width: 100%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    padding: 10px;
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: can you show us a live demo?

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0 auto;` to this ruleset:

From:

```
.bx-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

To:

```
.bx-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```